# Perl Slurp Regex Capture

Tags: regex, perl, capture

Using perl I have "slurped" in a large file that contains the text below and I am trying to capture all regex `$1` matches within the file for my given regex.  My regex is

```
=~ /((GET|PUT|POST|CONNECT).*?(Content-Type: (image\/jpeg)))/sgm
```

Currently the text in bold is being captured, however, the last capture is treating the lines

```
"GET /~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pscp.exe HTTP/1.1" to "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
```

as part of the very last capture and it should not b/c "text/html" is not equal to my regex capture of `(image\/jpeg)`.  I want to be able to capture the last capture without the

```
"GET /~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pscp.exe HTTP/1.1" to "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" being included.
```

Appreciate any help, thank you.

```
**GET /~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pscp.exe HTTP/1.1  
Host: the.earth.li  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0  
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Connection: Keep-Alive  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1  
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">  
<html><head>  
\.+"  
GET /~sgtatham/putty/0.62/x86/pscp.exe HTTP/1.1  
Host: the.earth.li  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0  
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Content-Length: 315392  
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99  
Connection: Keep-Alive  
Content-Type: image/jpeg**  
Platform: Digital Engagement Platform; Version: 1.1.0.0
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to capture. Can you please tell us what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easy do it with `(?!pattern)`, it's a negative look-ahead assertion.
For recap read this article [Positive examples of positive and negative lookahead (ourcraft.wordpress.com)](http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/positive-examples-of-positive-and-negative-lookahead/)

**Regular expression**

```
$text =~ /
(                                 # start capture
    (?:GET|PUT|POST|CONNECT)      # start phrase
    (?:
        (?!GET|PUT|POST|CONNECT)  # make sure we'havent any these phrase
        .                         # accept any character
    )*?                           # any number of times (not greedy) 
    Content-Type:\simage\/jpeg    # end phrase
)                                 # end capture
/msx;
print $1;
```

**All occurrences**

```
while($text =~ m/REGEXP/msxg) {

    print $1;
}
```

**Output**

```
GET /~sgtatham/putty/0.62/x86/pscp.exe HTTP/1.1  
Host: the.earth.li  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/13.0  
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5  
Content-Length: 315392  
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99  
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Comment: Thank you fxzuz for your posting, this looks close to what I want.  Would this solution match all occurences in the regex capture in a slurp file or match the first/last one only and then exit?  I need to match all occurences in a large slurp file wherever they may occur.  Thank you

Comment: Yes of course, just add g (global) to your regexp and process it in loop. I've added this piece of code to answer.

Comment: Hi fxzuz I have posted a new question in regards to a Perl problem I a trying to solve and was hoping you could take a look at it and help me out.  It is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/q/12417851/1508213 I appreciate any help you may provide.  Thank you